# android client side puts decimal points after a numeric value

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get JSON object in my android application, from restful web api.

**The code for that is**

```
 try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) newURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setReadTimeout(DATARETRIEVAL_TIMEOUT);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();       
     in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

When I read this input stream some of numeric values have decimal points.
is this conversion happening on android client side?

Comment: Just check the response using `Log.i("response", connection.getResponseMessage());`.

Comment: @Rojy Kumari: Nope its not. You are just receiving the response that's it.

Comment: @Chintan Soni response message is Ok

Comment: @Kevz: The point is, Server side is sending the values without any decimal but I am getting it with decimal. So can you suggest where is this conversion happening?

Comment: @RojyKumari: There is no such conversion in Android. How about u hit the url in browser and check the response?

Comment: @kevz yes, I have already done that and the response is without decimals

Comment: @RojyKumari: can u provide the url to check it my side.

Comment: @kevz Sorry,it requires some credentials which I cann't share

Comment: @rojy java cannot convert it to decimal until you do it. May be you are casting it to some float rather than integer type that's why may be the decimal occurs.

Comment: @kevz I have checked the response json on fiddler and postman as well and it is without any decimal point.

Comment: @RobinsGupta I am just reading the data from InputStream of httpurlconnection as you can see the code snippet I have posted.

Comment: @RojyKumari: change "POST" -> "GET" and setDoOutput(true); -> setDoOutput(false); and comment RequestProperty()

Comment: @kevz its a post request api

Comment: @RojyKumari: Just give it a try.

Comment: @kevz Its a post request web api, how can I write GET then, It ll eventually give the error "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' "

Comment: @RojyKumari: Have u tried it? No harm in trying rt...

Comment: @kevz I have tried it and I have provided you the exact error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100564/discussion-between-kevz-and-rojy-kumari).